# Cosa significa "cazzelappeso"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Siccome è suo fratello dormono nello stesso letto, nello stanzino con la finestra. Lena dice che non sta bene, e voleva che Vita dormisse con lei, ma Agnello preferisce dormirci lui con Lena. La vita è già abbastanza dura perché gli tocchi pure la condanna di andare a letto col figlio. Tanto Nicola pure se ha tredici anni c’ha il cervello di uno di cinque, è un **cazzelappeso**, stupido come una scarpa. A Vita suo fratello sembra balbuziente, ma ritardato proprio no.

Qualcuno di voi mi saprebbe spiegare il significato di "cazzelappeso"? Non ho trovato questo vocabolo su nessun dizionario.

Comment: hai mai pensato di contattare direttamente la Mazzucco per ottenere risposte quando non se ne trovano qui sui suoi romanzi? So che sulla sua pagina FB è molto disponibile e ci sono dei contatti. Inutile dire che non sto suggerendo di intasarle la posta o di non pubblicare domande (ed eventuali risposte) qui su SE, ma potrebbe essere un'ultima risorsa!

Comment: Potrebbe effettivamente appartenere al “lessico famigliare” della Mazzucco. Io ci sento, oltre ovviamente alla radice “cazzo”, un termine analogo a [“cazzabubbolo”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cazzabubbolo/), incrociato con l'andamento di [“vattelappesca”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/vattelappesca/), con anche la radice “appeso”, come a suggerire che il ragazzo in questione stia lì come un peso morto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La parola viene dal dialetto [minturnese](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minturno#Lingue_e_dialetti):

> Tutto questo mondo caleidoscopico si può rintracciare con facilità nella lingua che è certamente elegante, solida e soprattutto brillante, anche se spesso si mescola con l’immediatezza del **dialetto di Minturno o del gergo “broccolino” (come: “cazzelappeso”, p. 53;** “recchione”, p. 55; “Ti pozzi sbudellà”, p. 58; “abbruscià”, p. 59; …)
>
> - [Welcome to America e Bad- boys](https://lospecchiodicarta.it/2011/04/27/approfondimento-degli-studenti-su-vita-welcome-to-america-e-bad-boys/)
>   Lo Specchio de Carta - Osservatorio sul Romanzo Italiano Contemporaneo

e significa *babbeo*:

> Molto frequenti i regionalismi (appartenenti ai dialetti parlati tra basso Lazio e Campania: i personaggi  del romanzo provengono da Tufo di Minturno), come, per citare solo qualche parola particolarmente espressiva, *alleccamussi* “ceffoni”, *cacaturo* “latrina”, ***cazzelappeso* “babbeo”**...
>
> - [*Narrativa*](https://www.academia.edu/19431986/Narrativa), Luigi Matt